# react-bootstrap how to input only csv file and read this

Tags: react-bootstrap

I want to upload a file ( restricted to csv and xsl only) and read it. also want to sample data of it using react-bootstrap.

I new to react and react-bootstrap even html css.

till now I have used

```
        <input
            id="formControlsFile" type="file"
            accept=".csv"
            onChange={this.rhandleForce}
            ref={function(ref) { this.fileUpload = ref }.bind(this) }
        >
        </input>
```

this code reads only metadata of the file.
and this below

```
 <CSVReader
                cssClass="csv-input"
                accept=".csv"
                label="Select CSV with secret Death Star statistics"
                onFileLoaded={this.handleForce}
                onError={this.handleDarkSideForce}
                inputId="ObiWan"
            />
```

does not restric to upload only csv files but read the file.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the same thing. The component "Formcontrol" should be the responsible for doing that but it doesn't have the prop "accept". They should implement this.